# How to make a Highstocks x-axis even and regular?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ordinal

I am using the `highstocks` library for JavaScript to render some data collected as part of a school project.

While `highstocks` has proven great, the x-axis is acting up.

Due to interference, the collected data does not always come with neat intervals, and I would like the graph to reflect that.

Currently, the x-axis "jumps" in places.

I would like to have a regular x-axis with evenly spaced ticks.

Currently the `ordinal` value is set to `false`, which I would've expected to fix the x-axis.

The relevant settings are set:

```
var baseSettings = {
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },

    exporting: {
    enabled: false
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
         ordinal: false
    }
};
```

I feel like I've tried every possible permutation of settings at this point - perhaps someone more experienced can set me on the proper path?

An image of the problem can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b51Ny.jpg

The site can be found here:
cansat.sg.dk/graph/andoeya_droptest  (link disabled, as I can only post 2 links...)

The code is hosted on GitHub and can be found here:
https://github.com/dkkline/CanSat14-15/tree/master/presenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code isn't included in the question, but I'll address the issue.

You are using a `baseSettings` object and a custom settings object (lets call them `customSettings`) to form a chart. These two separate settings are merged using the jQuery `extend` function.

Your problem here is that when both `baseSettings` and `customSettings` both include the `xAxis` attribute they will not be merged because you are not using the `deep` variant of the `extend` function.

In short, you currently have this:

```
$(domIdent).highcharts('StockChart', $.extend({}, baseSettings, {
    // Custom settings
}));
```

Instead, use this (`true` added as first argument of `extend`):

```
$(domIdent).highcharts('StockChart', $.extend(true, {}, baseSettings, {
    // Custom settings
}));
```

See [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) for details on how this works, and why your current setup isn't working.

Summary of the parameter:

> **deep**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If true, the merge becomes recursive (aka. deep copy).

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have figured it out by myself.